# Why tap handler executes on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

On this page: http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/ (at the bottom)
when I click the green square (on desktop computer, FF), why the event handler for tap is executed?

I would like to ask for some resources

Comment: The answer is right there on the page you linked: `It is the gesture equivalent of a standard click event that is triggered on the release state of the touch gesture.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tap` and the `vclick` events are triggered at the same time. Basically the `vclick` event simulates a `click` event.

It allows mobile website to also work on PC and vice-versa.

You can find more information here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Here's a funny experiment:

If you do:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$( "div.box" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

function tapHandler( event ){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.type);
    $( event.target ).addClass( "tap" );
}
});
</script>
```

If you expand the first `console.log` result, you'll see that the type is "vclick", the second `console.log` will just show `tap`.